# Excel DDE Link: reading and writing in real time

Tags: excel, data-acquisition, commercial-package, real-time

I'm wondering if it is possible to link Excel and *Mathematica* in real time, so that *Mathematica* can be used as a computing and "storage" tool. Suppose I have an Excel spreadsheet **with an active DDE link**:

[image]

I would like to know if it is possible for *Mathematica* to communicate with Excel in real time **and** store every cell update in Excel. I know there is a package called ExcelLink, with several functions to link *Mathematica* and Excel. So, if I use, for instance `ExcelRead["A2"]` I get the correct value

> 19.36

However, it is not dynamic! I can get dynamic values by using

```
a=Dynamic[Refresh[ExcelRead["A2"], UpdateInterval -> 0]]
b=Dynamic[Refresh[ExcelRead["B2"], UpdateInterval -> 0]]
```

However, when I try to add `a+b` I get

> 19.36+28.56

And, worse, If I use

```
Dynamic[a+b, UpdateInterval -> 0]
```

I get

> 19.36+28.56

So, here arises my **first problem**: although *Mathematica* reads the values in real time from Excel, I'm not able to perform any calculation with them. Is there any way to do it?

My **second problem** is: how can I write dynamically the values I'm getting from the DDE Link inside Excel itself? I need to write **every updated value** in Excel in a sequence like shown below

[image]

Comment: Umm... you can't add two `Dynamic` objects!

Comment: @rm-rf It's funny, because I can do it in Excel, but not in Mathematica?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by doing it in Excel (I don't have Excel), but the `a` and `b` you have in _Mathematica_ have the head `Dynamic`, for which the operation `+` is not defined. What does `Dynamic[Setting@a + Setting@b, ...]` give?

Comment: @rm-rf wow.. it works!

Comment: @rm-rf What about the dynamic storage of updated values? Any idea how to do it? I don't mind to store them in Mathematica or Excel, by the way...

Comment: Again, I don't have Excel, so this is just a guess — could you perhaps use `ExcelPosition` to find the current position and increment it upon each refresh before writing to Excel (write to the incremented position)? You can use the second argument of `Dynamic`...

Comment: @rm-rf First: it's absolutely impressive that you don't have Excel... :-o You have convinced me that you're really a Mathematica fan! :-) Second: forget about Excel for a while... could you imagine any way to store these continuously updating values in Mathematica?

Comment: @rm-rf I've tried this: `list = {}` an then `Dynamic[Refresh[AppendTo[list, Setting@a], UpdateInterval -> 0]]`, but my list grows in a crazy pace!

Comment: Well, I've just never needed Excel in my life and I use LaTeX for all my Word/Powerpoint needs, so I've not needed the entire Office suite either. Why do you use `UpdateInterval -> 0`? Can't you do it slower? What's the point in updating like crazy if you don't need to? You'll quickly run out of memory at this rate...

Comment: What is a DDE link? I presume it's some other external feed that updates your Excel sheet with fresh data?

Comment: @rm-rf I'm working with financial data in real time... sometimes the amount of data received in one second is crazy high! I need to capture all this data in real time...

Comment: @rm-rf That's true... DDE link is an external feed for Excel.

Comment: Ah, Ok. Hmm... Doesn't the Wolfram Financial Platform have something for this? (or is it a separate paid app?)

Comment: @rm-rf Actually the Wolfram Financial Platform is pretty weak for most of the needs of the financial industry...

Comment: In any case, I'm not sure it's a good idea to just refresh at a high rate, since you might end up re-reading the same cell repeatedly, leading to duplicate values (which then might be indistinguishable from non-sampling related duplicates). Perhaps you might be able to read the current position, store it in mma, then at the next update, check to see if the size of that column has changed, and if so, read the block from current position till new position (looks like `ExcelRange` might help)

Comment: Also, `Append` and friends create a copy each time so your performance will take a hit as the list grows... you might have to use linked lists (but needs more care in handling it)

Comment: @rm-rf That's why I wanted to store the data directly into Excel... I was wondering something like `Dynamic[Refresh[Excel[counter]=Setting@a,UpdateInterval->.1]`. This would put the storage load in Excel, instead of Mathematica... I'm still wondering how to create this "counter" so it dynamically refreshes itself to A7, A8, A9, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research I've found this **partial** solution:

**Step 1**: Open Excel (if you have it!)

**Step 2**: Open Excel Link

```
Needs["ExcelLink`"]
```

**Step 3**: If you don't have any DDE Link for Excel, *simulate* real time data using

```
Dynamic[Refresh[Excel["B1"] = RandomInteger[100], UpdateInterval -> 1]]
```

**Step 4**: Import back to *Mathematica* your simulated data

```
a = Dynamic[Refresh[ExcelRead["B1"], UpdateInterval -> 1]]
```

**Step 5**: Create a numberic list and set `Dynamic[]` to append sequential numbers to it every 1 second

```
numlist = {}; k = 1;
num = Dynamic[Refresh[AppendTo[numlist, k++];Last@numlist, UpdateInterval -> 1], TrackedSymbols -> {}]
```

**Step 6**: Create a string list (for cell values) and set `Dynamic[]` to append sequential values to it every 1 second

```
cellslist = {}; j = 1;
cell = Dynamic[Refresh[AppendTo[cellslist, "A" <> ToString[Last[numlist]]];Last@cellslist, UpdateInterval -> 1], TrackedSymbols -> {}]
```

**Step 7**: Store the values in Excel itself!!! (thanks to @rm-rf for the `Setting` tip!)

```
Dynamic[Refresh[Excel[Last@cellslist] = Setting@a, UpdateInterval -> 1]]
```

**Result**

[image]

## **IMPORTANT**

This is a solution using `UpdateInterval->1` . However, I would appreciate any solution with asynchronous reading and writing in real time.